# Two Twitter API requests formatted identically- one posts but one gives 401

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth, axios, twitter-oauth

I'm using [oauth-1.0a](https://github.com/ddo/oauth-1.0a) to generated signed request headers, and [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to send my HTTP requests from Node.js. My [swap token POST request](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/access_token) in the 3 legged auth works successfully (as does a GET request to retrieve my profile using said token), but a [POST status request](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update) using nearly identical code and the tokens provided just return a 401 Error 32.

The working request (using a request token to fetch an oauth token):

```js
async swapToken(data: TwitterAccessTokenRequest) {

        const { oauth_token, oauth_verifier, oauth_consumer_key, oauth_token_secret } = data;
        const oauth = new OAuth({
            consumer: {
                key: this.app.get('twitter').clientId,
                secret: this.app.get('twitter').clientSecret,
            },
            signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
            hash_function(base_string, key) {
                return crypto
                    .createHmac('sha1', key)
                    .update(base_string)
                    .digest('base64')
            },
        });

        const token = {
            key: oauth_token,
            secret: oauth_token_secret
        }

        const request = {
            url: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
            method: 'POST',
            data: { oauth_verifier, oauth_token, oauth_consumer_key }
        };

        try {
            const json = await axios.post(request.url, request.data, { headers: oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize(request, token))});
            return json.data.split('&').map(item => item.split('=')).map(i => ({[i[0]] : i[1]})).reduce((newObj, current) => ({...newObj, ...current}), {});
        } catch (e) {
            logger.error(e);
            throw new BadRequest('Error fetching auth token from Twitter');
        }
    }
```

The request returning a 401 (using the token/secret returned in the previous request, in the same format):

```js
async sendTweet(data: TwitterApiPostStatusRequest) {

        const { oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, status, attachment_url, media_ids } = data;
        const oauth = new OAuth({
            consumer: {
                key: this.app.get('twitter').clientId,
                secret: this.app.get('twitter').clientSecret,
            },
            signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
            hash_function(base_string, key) {
                return crypto
                    .createHmac('sha1', key)
                    .update(base_string)
                    .digest('base64')
            },
        });

        const token = {
            key: oauth_token,
            secret: oauth_token_secret
        }

        const request = {
            url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                status,
                attachment_url
            }
        };

        if(media_ids) {
            request['data']['media_ids'] = media_ids;
        }

        try {
            const json = await axios.post(request.url, request.data, { headers: oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize(request, token))});
            return json.data;
        } catch (e) {
            logger.error(e);
            return new BadRequest('Error sending tweet to Twitter');
        }
    }
```

I've tried sending the request body specifically as form data, tried sending the whole thing in the request body as per the oauth-1.0a examples, nothing seems to have a difference. Any suggestions?

Comment: Uh, the working request is missing, I think.

Comment: Yep lost focus on the editor and hit enter, apologies. Fixed now.